# sort a list with equivalence classes

Tags: python, performance, sorting

I'm trying to optimize the following function `f`, written in python.
It is a function of an integer `k`.
First it calls another function `G(k)`, which gives back a long list of certain objects. We want to manipulate this list as follows: two elements `a,b` are equivalent iff the function `H` (which is a given function that can take values 0 or 1) evalutated on them is one, `H(a,b)=1`; our function `f` should give back a list of equivalence classes of elements in `G(k)`. An element of the list should be of the form (representative element, number of elements in that class).

That's what my code below does, but I wonder if it can be optimized, considering that `G(k)` can be a very long list. For the moment I'd like to regard `G` and `H` as given.

```
def f(k):
    L = G(k)
    y = len(L)
    R = []
    for i in range(y):
        nomatch = 0
        for j in range(len(R)):
            if H(L[i],R[j][0]):
                R[j][1] += 1
                nomatch = 1
                break
        if nomatch == 0: R.append([L[i],1])
    return R
```

Edit1: I do not care particularly about readability (it's 13 lines of code after all), just performance. You should regard G and H as black boxes, the first outputs a list of numbers (in first approximation), the second 1 or 0.

Comment: Did you get this challenge from a website? If so please could you link to the site. Thank you.

Comment: What is `H` and what are the objects returned by `G`? Are they instances of a class which you can change? Can you convert this from a comparison function to a unique identifier method that returns the same for equivalent objects?

Comment: Micro-review: the code would benefit from improved comments.

Comment: @Peilonrayz No.

Comment: @Graipher I cannot change H and G. I'd like to keep them as abstract as possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight What is unclear?

Comment: If the function itself were better named, and the variables too, then there wouldn't be so much need for comments.  But this is lacking even a docstring, and `f` conveys nothing as a name.  How is a future reader expected to pick up the necessary context?

Comment: (While I'm comfortable with calling *categorisation* *sorting*, the caption of tag [tag:sorting] reads *Sorting is the process of applying some order to a collection of items.* which does *not* seem to apply here

Comment: @Graipher You are right, I already did that, but in the end it reduces again to optimize 'sorting' of the list.

Comment: @greybeard Sure, what would be more appropriate tag?

Answer (score 2):

Let me try and illustrate the difference *naming* and [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) make -
ah, well, iterating over sequences and `for…else`, as well:

```
def collatz_list(k, s=[]):
    """ append the list of collatz values starting from k to s. """
    s.append(k)
    return s if k <= 1 else collatz_list(
        k//2 if 0 == k % 2 else k * 3 + 1, s)


def equivalent(l, r):
    """ return "equivalent" when congruent mod 42. """
    return l % 42 == r % 42


def categorise(k, G, H):
    """ categorise the results of G(k) according to predicate H"""
    many_items = G(k)
    categories = []
    for item in many_items:
        for pair in categories:
            if H(item, pair[0]):
                pair[1] += 1
                break
        else:
            categories.append([item, 1])
    return categories


def g(k):
    """ return the list of collatz values starting from k. """
    return collatz_list(k)


def h(l, r):
    """ return "equivalent" when congruent mod 42. """
    return equivalent(l, r)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(categorise(7, g, h))
```

Comment: Had no luck trying to improve readability/elegance using `if (not any(map(lambda pair:…`.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing anything more about the nature of G or H, there isn't much to go on.  This might not be *optimized*, but it is more readable.  It takes as arguments the sequence output by `G(k)` and the function `H`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def f(sequence, is_equivalent):
    """returns the number items in each equivalence class in the input sequence"""
    counter = defaultdict(int)

    for item in sequence:
        # filter counter.keys() to find equivalents to item
        equivalent = (eq for eq in counter.keys() if is_equivalent(item, eq))

        # key is next equivalent or default to item if no equivalent
        key = next(equivalent, item)

        counter[key] += 1

    return list(counter.items())
```

Comment: I see readability improved. In the question I do not see indication objects from `G` to be suitable as keys for dicts, let alone *un*suitable.

Comment: @greybeard True, the objects from `G` might not be suitable as keys.  In that case, one could use their index in the sequence as keys.

Comment: `use [index of non-hashable objects in an existing] sequence as keys` *nice*